# Jquery siblings() not working for element inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been stuck with this for quite some time now.

I want to get the values of input fields on click using jquery, but it always alerts "undefined"

```js
$('.inputbox .updateAdvertiser').on('click', function() {
    var name = $(this).siblings('.name').val();
    var adId = $(this).siblings('.adId').val();
    alert(adId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="inputbox">
    <input type="text" class="name" value="mark">
    <label>Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputbox">
    <input type="text" class="adId" value="1">
    <label>Userid</label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputbox">
    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="updateAdvertiser">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="inputbox">
    <input type="text" class="name" value="Peter">
    <label>Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputbox">
    <input type="text" class="adId" value="2">
    <label>Userid</label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputbox">
    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="updateAdvertiser">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

siblings won't work outside parent element

```js
$('.inputbox .updateAdvertiser').on('click', function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.box');
    var name = parent.find('.name').val();
    var adId = parent.find('.adId').val();
    alert(adId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="inputbox">
    <input type="text" class="name" value="mark">
    <label>Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputbox">
    <input type="text" class="adId" value="1">
    <label>Userid</label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputbox">
    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="updateAdvertiser">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="inputbox">
    <input type="text" class="name" value="Peter">
    <label>Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputbox">
    <input type="text" class="adId" value="2">
    <label>Userid</label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputbox">
    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="updateAdvertiser">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! This answered my question perfectly